# How can I hyperlink a word in the subject line?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, subject

I was trying to manipulate the html code of the subject line like that:

`I am subject<a href="...">#001</a>`

But the subject line can not HTML. Is there any other way I can hyperlink a word in the subject line?

Comment: As you said, subject cannot contain HTML. How would having a link on the subject line benefit you, though?

Comment: Is this even possible to have hyperlink in Subj? Do you have an example? Screenshot with such hyperlink? Or rather what problem are you solving?

Comment: I wouldn't think this is possible... I've certainly never seen it done in practice and if I did, it would probably throw up a couple of red flags for malicious content.

Comment: Outlook will display the combining-low-line unicode character a̲b̲c̲d̲e̲f̲g̲ but it's a bit wonky, will depend somewhat on the users font choice & as mentioned would strongly resemble a spammers trick.

Answer (score 0):

## No, you cannot.

HTML markup in mail headers is not supported by any email specification. Therefore, **no**, you cannot hyperlink a word in the subject line.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, put if you put a link in the subject (starting with http:// or https://), Outlook will show it as a link.

Comment: So for Outlook it seems to be possible to change properties of a word. Is there really no way to do that as well?

Comment: No. Subject is always plain text. It is just Outlook is smart enough to display the links dynamically when it detects a url.